# Is there a limit on mobile html video playsinline?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I can't play a video on iPhone 5 with this code :

```html
<video preload="auto" playsinline muted autoplay="false">
  <source src="videos/film-1080.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="videos/film-1080.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Is there a limit on mobile html video playsinline ?
Size ? Width/height ? Weight ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Does the browser you're using support this tag?

Comment: Yes, I use Safari.

Comment: What iOS version?

Comment: Safari does not support webm

Comment: Yes, there is a size limit, I think based on the mobile and network bandwidth. I am not sure. But I know there is a size limit. Does anyone know what is the limit on an IOS 10 and above

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm), iOS Safari does not support webm. This could be your issue.